# Webforms Routing ignore Elmah

Tags: asp.net, webforms, url-routing

I am having some trouble getting Elmah to work with url routing in an asp.net webforms application. Elmah is mapped to "elmah.aspx" and I have tried a couple of variations on:

```
routes.Add(new Route("elmah.aspx", new StopRoutingHandler()));
```

Is there a way I can ignore all .aspx pages?

Comment: Hi luke, I have a really similar problem using web forms. how did you ignore elmah route at the end? thanks for your time on this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATED:

Please look at step 4 on the [elmah Google Code page](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/MVC).

To ignore all .aspx files. You just do:

```
routes.Add(new Route("*\.aspx", new StopRoutingHandler()));
```

You could also do:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("*\.aspx");
```

Please refer to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx).

Comment: Combo of this and fixing some web.config stuff cleared it up, thanks